# How to synchronize Stack?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm a beginner in Java. I have written this simple code which which accept integer data from the user and push it in Stack. Thread is continuously checking if the size of the stack == 3. Once the stack reaches this size,thread is popping out the element from Stack. I understand Stack is not synchronized. Hence I have used Collection.Synchronized method to synchronized it.

Will this implementation work ?

```
    import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackSyncronisation<Item> extends Thread{
    private Stack<Item> s1;

    public StackSyncronisation(){
        s1=new Stack<Item>();
        Collections.synchronizedList(s1);
    }

public void run(){

        //System.out.println("Inside run method");
        while(true){

            if(s1.size()==3){
                {
                while(!s1.isEmpty()){

                    // Poping out 
                    System.out.println("Poping out from Stack");
                    s1.pop();

                        }
                }

            }

        }

    }

public void push(Item d){


    s1.push(d);

}


    public static void main(String[]argc){


        StackSyncronisation<Integer> x1=new StackSyncronisation<Integer>();

        x1.start();


Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){

            System.out.println("Enter 1:Push");
            //in.nextInt();

            switch (in.nextInt()) {
            case 1: x1.push(in.nextInt());              
                    break;

            default:
                break;
            }



        }


    }



}
```

Comment: "Will this implementation work ?" - write some tests....

Answer (score 3):

**Java stacks *are* synchronized.** `Stack` extends [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), which is synchronized. Both are semi-deprecated. It's recommended to use `ArrayDeque` in place of `Stack`, and `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`. However, since you actually *want* synchronization in this case, maybe you should just stick with `Stack`.

This doesn't do anything:

```
Collections.synchronizedList(s1);
```

`Collections.synchronizedList` returns a wrapped version of the collection, but since you're not saving the returned value it doesn't actually do anything but waste resources. `s1` is still pointing to the unwrapped stack, but since `Stack` is already synchronized this is probably fine. You should just drop the call to `synchronizedList`.

Just from the synchronization standpoint, I think what you've posted should work fine. It looks like you'll have one or more threads pushing to the stack, but only one thread popping from the stack. In that case, you're guaranteed that `s1` won't already be empty when you try to `pop()` from it. If you have multiple threads popping from the stack then this code isn't safe because tons of stuff can happen between where you check `size()==3` and attempt to `pop()`.

Comment: ,Thanks for quick reply  Quick question : So the thread will lock the stack until it pops out all element or just one element ?

Comment: @user3792088 - The synchronization is _within_ the stack. When you call a method on the stack, that method call happens "atomically", but as soon as you start talking about two or more calls then all bets are off. You'd need separate synchronization to handle that.